# Android Create ImageView with 3 rounded and 1 straight corner

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create an image view with 3 rounded and one straight corner.

Setting background drawable doesn't work and I did find some java code but it only rounds 2 corners or 4 and not 3

```
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 
bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = pixels;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new 
PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

return output;
```

[image: The resultant image should be as attached]

Answer (score 1):

Create new drawable resource file in drawable file and set background to drawable file.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- set the transparent background to image view -->
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

<!-- Replace the corner value with suitable value -->
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

And apply the proper scaletype attribute in the xml file.

1. `CENTER` – Center the image but doesn’t scale the image
2. `CENTER_CROP` –Scale the image uniformly
3. `CENTER_INSIDE` – Center the image inside the container
4. `FIT_CENTER`– Scale the image from center
5. `FIT_END` – Scale the image from the end of the container.
6. `FIT_START` – Scale the image from start of the container
7. `FIT_XY` – Fill the image from x and y coordinates of the container
8. `MATRIX` – Scale using the image matrix when drawing

Answer (score 1):

There are well written libraries out there such that you can clip an image to any path you want, but here is the code:

```
private Bitmap clip(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);


    // creating a closing path with 3 rounded corners
    Path path = new Path();
    float radius = 48;
    float diameter = radius * 2;
    float width = bitmap.getWidth();
    float height = bitmap.getHeight();
    path.addArc(0, 0, diameter, diameter, 180, 90);
    path.lineTo(width - radius, 0);
    path.arcTo(width - diameter, 0, width, diameter, 270, 90, false);
    path.lineTo(width, height);
    path.lineTo(radius, height);
    path.arcTo(0, height - diameter, diameter, height, 90, 90, false);
    path.close();


    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    return output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in Drawable @background.xml file. inside

```
 <corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" 
      android:topRightRadius="6dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp" 
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

Then use as background for Imageview